# Which dotnet core download do I upgrade with (windows 2016 hosting)

Tags: asp.net-core, upgrade, windows-server-2016

On a Windows 2016 server I run a single asp.net core 2.03 IIS hosted site.
The server has dotnet core 2.03 installed:

(dir (Get-Command dotnet).Path.Replace('dotnet.exe', 'shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App')).Name
[image]

On the development machine I have upgraded to dotnet core 2.1.

Which download from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows must I use to upgrade the window 2016 server to 2.1?

The "Hosting Bundle Installer Runtime link" downloads a file named "dotnet-hosting-2.1.1-win". Previous downloads where named "DotNetCore.2.0.3-WindowsHosting".
[image]

Answer (score 3):

On your server, you will need to install the .NET Core Runtime Hosting Bundle. The name of the executable has changed in the past, so yeah, it was `DotNetCore.2.0.x-WindowsHosting.exe` in the past but is now `dotnet-hosting-2.1.x-win.exe`

The correct link to the hosting bundle is on [this download page of the 2.1.1 runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/runtime-2.1.1): [.NET Core 2.1.1 Hosting Bundle Installer](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.1.1-windows-hosting-bundle-installer).

If you want to run your ASP.NET Core application that runs on .NET Core 2.1, then you will have to install the runtime on your server. You don’t *necessarily* need the hosting bundle unless you are hosting your application inside IIS. Otherwise, you can also just download the runtime installer instead.

You do *not* need to install the SDK on your server, so you getting the error that the SDK folder does not exist is perfectly fine.